# Subclassing a Python class to inherit attributes of super class

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm trying to inherit attributes from a super class but they are not being initialized correctly:

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute1 = "attribute1"

class OtherThing(Thing):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Thing, self).__init__()
        print self.attribute1
```

This throws an error since attribute1 is not an attribute of OtherThing, even though Thing.attribute1 exists. I thought this was the correct way to inherit and extend a super class. Am I doing something wrong? I don't want to create an instance of Thing and use its attributes, I need it to inherit this for simplicity.

Comment: You want `super(OtherThing, self).__init__()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to give, as [argument](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions), the class name (where it is being called) to `super()`:

```
super(OtherThing, self).__init__()
```

According to [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super):

> ... `super` can be used to refer to parent classes **without naming them
>   explicitly**, thus making the code more maintainable.

so you are not supposed to give the *parent class*. 
See this example from [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) too:

```
class C(B):
    def method(self, arg):
        super(C, self).method(arg)
```

Answer (score 3):

Python3 makes this easy:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute1 = "attribute1"

class OtherThing(Thing):
    def __init__(self):
        #super(Thing, self).__init__()
        super().__init__()
        print(self.attribute1)

def main():
    otherthing = OtherThing()

main()
```